# Why can't I use the constructor of a case class as a function for use inside map()

Tags: scala, lambda, case-class, parser-combinators, fastparse

Passing the tuple directly to the constructor is not accepted by the compiler as the minimal example shows:

```
scala> case class A(a:Int, b:Int)
defined class A

scala> List((1, 2)).map(A)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
found   : A.type
required: ((Int, Int)) => ?
    List((1, 2)).map(A)
                        ^

scala> List((1, 2)).map(A _)
<console>:14: error: _ must follow method; cannot follow A.type
    List((1, 2)).map(A _)
                        ^
```

Scala parser combinators have the operator `^^` for that.
Is there something similar in fastparse library?

Comment: One thing is a function from a tuple and another thing is a function of two arguments. Anyways, you can do `map(A.tupled)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `.tupled`

```
List((1, 2)).map(A.tupled)
```

The reason this doesn't work "out of the box" is because `A` expects two parameters of type `Int`, not a tuple of `(Int, Int)`. `tupled` lifts `(A, A)` into `((A, A))`.

You can verify this by modifying `A`'s constructor:

```
final case class A(tup: (Int, Int))
```

And then this works:

```
List((1, 2)).map(A)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because the following:

```
List((1, 2)).map(A)
```

translates to:

```
List((1, 2)).map(x => A(x))
```

But the `A` constructor takes two integers as parameters instead of `Tuple2[Int, Int]`. You would have to define a constructor that takes a tuple of two integers.